# NodeJs Heroku Deployment Failing on Build

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I am simply trying to build my web application to Heroku. I am able to "build" my client locally, but for some reason, when Heroku is building it when I **git push heroku master**, the build is failing on...

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Authentication/login' in '/tmp/build_9709419844244c794729ea02221256db/client/src'
```

This component exists and is being built locally when I run **npm run build**. My server package.json is as follows:

```
{
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "This is the server",
"engines": {
"node": "9.8.x"
 },
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node server",
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client/ && npm install && npm run build",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"cacheDirectories": [
"node_modules",
"client/node_modules"
],
"author": "Chris and Patrick",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"body-parser": "^1.18.3",
"dotenv": "^6.0.0",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"firebase": "^5.5.0",
"firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
"jimp": "^0.5.3",
"mime-types": "^2.1.20",
"multer": "^1.4.0",
    "uuid-v4": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Above is my main package.json file.

I tried to clear build cache and run production build again but received the error below:

```
Cannot run one-off process at this time. Please try again later.
```

Comment: Install locally but rm node_modules so simulate full install. Should repro in local the same error

Comment: Hey Robert. I deleted node_modules in client, ran an install && build locally and it worked perfectly fine. 

The Heroku build is still broken in the exact same spot.

Comment: heroku run bash to shell into the remote to try to understand why files/ packages that build puts correctly on localhost are not getting there on the remote\

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue.

The problem was github does not recognize folder name case changes. I had to rename each component folder and re-push to heroku master. Worked fine.